# One javascript function causes "unexpected identifier" error from a DIFFERENT function

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm calling the following function inside of a link's `onClick` attribute. There are two such links on the page. When I click one of the links. Everything works fine. When I click the other link, I get an "unexpected identifier error" from the **other** function.

According to Chrome's console. The error is "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier." and it originates from the function **that I didn't click**, at the line indicated by the comments in the code below.

Why is this happening?

```
<a href="#" onClick="
    FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            link: 'http://www.mydomain.com',
            show_error: true,
            display: 'popup',
        },

        function (response) {

            //ERROR IS HERE

            console.log( 'After FB.ui()' );                 
            jQuery.post(
                '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                {
                    action : 'fb_invite_milestone',
                    postID : MyAjax.postID
                }
            );
        }     
    );
">LINK</a>
```

**Update:**
SOLVED! ...but I'm embarrassed to say why. Read my answer below to see how stupid I am.

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: syntax errors don't happen at runtime, they happen because there's a syntax error in your code so it's not valid javascript. what does the onclick code look like?

Comment: If you have made changes to your scripts, you need to reopen (close and open) the developer tools for Chrome to take the changes

Comment: flem: i can't replicate this on jsfiddle because the function is calling the Facebook API, which only works on the authorized domain.


@Andy Ray: the onClick code is exactly what you see above (inside onClick=" ... ")

Comment: I don't see `onClick=` anywhere above?

Comment: Just updated it. Also, slightly more informative error from Firefox.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why on Earth are you still using the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: @TiesonT. There's a long but not very interesting reason why it's set up this way. Does the onClick attribute have any relevance to this question or are you just curious?

Comment: @Emerson Depends. When I see inline code like that I tend to not be surprised when there are errors. HTML parsers are funny animals...

Comment: Just for giggles, perhaps adding a `return false;` to the end of each function would help.

Comment: @TiesonT. Tried adding `return false;` but no luck. Do you think the fact that the code is in `onClick` might be the problem? It would take some work, but I could change it if we think that's a real potential solution.

Comment: @Emerson Hard to say, but it feels like JavaScript embedded into an HTML element other than a `<script>` tag is prone to the idiosyncrasies of the HTML parser. I've never written it that way, though, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @TiesonT. & @Andy Ray
Breaking news: When I comment out the entire `jQuery.post()` inside the callback function the error goes away. Not sure why, but at least this narrows down the possibilities somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no!! TOTALLY STUPID MISTAKE: The PHP block inside the callback function was breaking the js syntax because in one instance the function was already inside `<?php ?>` and in the other it was not. I missed it because the syntax highlighting was confused by the fact that it was inside a string.

Comment: Just FYI, if you solved your own question, you are allowed to mark your own answer as the solution. :)